# AJAX request returns 200 but response body is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, http

I have a jQuery AJAX call, which returns `200`, but response body is empty.

```
$.ajax({
    method: 'GET',
    url: api,
    data: {
        'action': 'check',
        'ip': hostname
    },
    success: function(result) { ... },
    dataType: 'json'
});
```

I copy the actual request URL generated by the AJAX call into the browser, and I get the desired output (JSON).

`https://example.com/sub/folder/index.php?action=check&ip=1.2.3.4`

What could be wrong with the AJAX call?

Comment: Are you making a cross-domain AJAX request? Have you looked at the console or dev tools after attempting to make the request to check for errors?

Comment: Did you check the network tab when making the AJAX request?

Comment: did u try `$.getJSON`

Comment: @xdeepakv that won't make any difference

Comment: yeah! can check with fetch("url", {mode: "no-cors"}) If issue, will throw exception

Comment: So does jQuery.

Comment: "but response body is empty" — How are you determining this? Have you checked the Network tab of the browser's developer tools?

Comment: @xdeepakv — Don't do that. Adding `no-cors` will make it fail **silently** *without* throwing an exception in many cases.

Comment: Yes, I checked the Network tab. That's how I knew response was empty. @VLAZ

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan hmm, yes it's a cross-domain AJAX request

Comment: That's your problem then. In the console there's probably a big error about missing CORS/Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers in the response

Comment: @Obay — Does the success function fire at all? Have you added `console.log` to check?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan that seems to be it. Didn't notice it before since it's not an error, just a warning: `Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response <URL> with MIME type application/json` Thanks for the lead.

Comment: @Quentin yes the success function fires.